# How to add badge to native base tabs?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am a beginner in react native, trying to design a simple page, where we show badge in tabs. I am using the native base for tabs and badges. The native base docs tells how to create a badge, but I couldn't find how to add these badges to tabs. Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a badge on your tabs, pass the badge with TabHeading to heading prop of Tab component.

```
<Tab
  heading={
    <TabHeading>
      <Badge success>
        <Text>2</Text>
      </Badge>
    </TabHeading>
  }>
  <Tab1 />
</Tab>
```